# Convex tilings of the plane

Tags: combinatorial-geometry, tiling

For convex polyhedra you have Steinitz's theorem characterizing them as the 3-connected planar graphs. My question is not about spheric tilings, but about periodic tilings of the euclidean plane. Is it here also the case that 3-connectivity corresponds with convexity?

It is easy to construct an example of a 2-connected periodic tiling that is not convex. My guess is that the symmetry group prohibits some tilings from being convex and thus there are also 3-connected periodic tilings that are not convex, but I can't seem to be able to construct a counter example to support this guess.

Is there a known counterexample for this? Or is it actually true? Any reference or hint would help.

edit: I was looking for a periodic tiling which has no equivariantly equivalent (i.e. topologically equivalent and the same symmetry group) tiling that is convex and that is 3-connected when you look at the segments as graph edges. My feeling is that in case of the euclidean plane there might be a tiling in which you can't convexify one face, without needing to make another one nonconvex to keep the same symmetry group.

Answer (score 4):

You are perhaps thinking of [Tutte's "spring" theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fary_theorem#Related_results) that every 3-connected graph has an embedding with convex faces.  It indeed a corollary of the (earlier) [Steinitz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_theorem), but Tutte's proof is of independent interest.  Now, for periodic networks in the plane, you need to look at the "torus version" of the Tutte theorem.  Start with [this important paper](http://www.cs.harvard.edu/~sjg/papers/tutte.pdf) which gives a version of the result and check some further refs therein.

Comment: It may be that you answered a different question than what nvcleemp intended?  Not certain. Rather than asking if a tiling could be convexified à la Tutte, I interpreted the question as asking whether there is a tiling with nonconvex pieces, which, if unaltered geometrically and with its segments interpreted as graph edges, is 3-connected. 

Comment: Yes, maybe I forgot to add some things which were to obvious for me, because I've been working with those restrictions some time now.

I was looking for a periodic tiling which has no equivariantly equivalent (i.e. topologically equivalent and the same symmetry group) tiling that is convex and that is 3-connected when you look at the segments as graph edges.

I'll also add this part to the original question.

Comment: but thanks already for this answer: I'll certainly read the article.